# How to handle exception in listagg() function

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I am using listagg in my script

```
listagg(' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL  || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS|| ' |' ||  CHR(10)) within group (order by aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR)) as activity
```

When listagg exceed 4000 bytes all script fail. How can I handle exception and for this record insert e.x. NULL and go to the next record without fail.

Comment: Why can't you substr() you insert string making it less or eq. to 4000?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give me any example? E.x I have string which will contain 12000 bytes. Can you write how it should looks like? to get final result which will contain all 12000 bytes ordered properly at the end

Comment: No way to do like that in 11g. 12000 > varchar2 maximum (4000 in <= 11g) => it's not working with varchar2; you can try with CLOB, but listagg returns only varchar2 => no way then. Or use 12g which has increased a maximum size of varchar2 to 32767, which only moves the restriction upper but does not remove it at all

Comment: I meant exactly what i wrote - Substr() your string to 4000 bytes, then listagg(). If your table column is 4000 bytes, then what is the point trying to insert 12000? Subtr() it to 4000.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I use my own example to show the idea, because I simply have no German layout and your tables as well:

```
with src as (/* overflow */
             select 1 id, level lv
             from dual
             connect by level <= 10000
             union all
             /* fitting */
             select 2, level lv
             from dual
             connect by level <= 10
             union all
             select 3, level lv
             from dual
             connect by level <= 5)
select listagg(case when length_ <= 4000 then lv end,',') within group (order by lv)
from (select id,lv,sum(length(lv) + 1) over (partition by id) - 1 length_ from src)
group by id
```

The idea:

1. src is your table, id is the value you are grouping by, level is your value
2. this subquery `select id,lv,sum(length(lv) + 1) over (partition by id) - 1 length_ from src` gathers the future length of `listagg` result, `+ 1` is made for delimeter `','`, `- 1` is done for the last delimeter which is not used
3. expression `listagg(case when length_ <= 4000 then lv end,',') within group (order by lv)` checks if the length is less than allowed value (4000), if it is overflown it returns null

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help Simon. To be honest I don't fully understood your code. what is represented by                                    1.level <= 10000 and level<=10 and level <=5 ?        <br/>            2. dual table? Should I use my own table here or dual table?  <br/>            3. Can I send you my query and you will see what I did wrong?<br/>           Thank you in advance

Comment: hi, **1** is about to generate data sets from 1 to 10000, 1 to 10 and 1 to 5. First one should overflow the varchar2 max length (4000), two others do not. **2** dual table is a system table which has one row, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table for more info. It is common to use it in any code, it is presented I think in every Oracle DB. **3** yes, of course, send it but I don't know the way to do it here... Simply attach it to your question, leave only important part which does not work and change names to be more private. Sometimes when you do this it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should count SUM of LENGTH of strings for each group. And then use CASE to handle if this sum length > 4000. In the following query I join original table and a table with `SUM(LENGTH)` for each group. Try this:

```
select t.id,
       CASE WHEN (TL.SumLen<=4000)
              THEN LISTAGG(t.Str,',') 
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Str)
                          OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID)
            ELSE NULL
       END
FROM t 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT Id, SUM(LENGTH(str||',')) SumLen
         FROM t 
         GROUP BY ID
 ) TL on T.id=TL.id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db200/16)</kbd>

Comment: @Simon Sorry I didn't read your answer. Now I see that idea is the same but my answer isn't exact copy of your answer. So +1 to your answer.

Comment: no problem, sometimes it happens :) anyway the main line is the same and I think it is not a solution to show nulls instead of overflown value. It should be somehow truncated, and the only idea I see is to create an own analytic function... But this will lose the ordering possibility. So, the only way, probably, is to do it in a PL/SQL block

Answer (score 0):

@Simon : here is the code

```
 drop table  Project.Iterations;
    drop table  Project.test_steps;
    CREATE TABLE Project.TEST_STEPS
    (
    test_case_id NUMBER(9,0),
    test_step varchar2(4000)

    );

    CREATE TABLE Project.TEST_CASES_WITHOUT_TEST_STEPS
    (
    test_case_id NUMBER(9,0)

    );

    INSERT INTO Project.TEST_STEPS(test_case_id,test_step)
    select test_case_id ,
    listagg(activity, chr(10)) within group (order by header1 ) as test_step

    from(
    select 
    testschrit.testfall_id as test_case_id,

     'h2.' || TESTSCHRITT_NR || ' ' || CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(600))  || CHR(10)  || CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(600)) as header1,



    ('h2.' || TESTSCHRITT_NR || ' ' || CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(600))  || CHR(10)  || CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(600)) 
    || '||AKTIVITÄT_NR' || '||AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL' || '||AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG' || '||AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS||' ||  CHR(10)  
    /*|| clobagg(' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS|| ' |' ||  CHR(10))  as activity*/
    || listagg(' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_KÜRZEL  || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_BESCHREIBUNG || ' |' || aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_ERWARTETES_ERGEBNIS|| ' |' ||  CHR(10)) within group (order by aktiv.AKTIVITÄT_NR)) as activity  





    FROM Project.TESTFALLBESCHREIBUNG tfb, Project.TESTSCHRITTE testschrit, Project.AKTIVITÄTEN aktiv
    WHERE testschrit.testfall_id = tfb.testfall_id(+)
    AND  testschrit.TESTSCHRITT_ID=aktiv.TESTSCHRITT_ID (+)



    Group by 
    testschrit.testfall_id,
    testschrit.testschritt_id,
    testschrit.TESTSCHRITT_NR,
    CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(600)),
    CAST(TESTSCHRITT_BESCHREIBUNG AS varchar(600))

    order by test_case_id,
    testschrit.testschritt_nr



    )

    group by test_case_id;

    CREATE TABLE Project.ITERATIONS
    (
    Issue_Id NUMBER(9,0),
    iteration_id NUMBER(9,0),
    content_of_iteration VARCHAR2(4000),
    parent_id NUMBER(9,0),
    Issue_type VARCHAR2(300),
    Hierarchy1 VARCHAR2(300),
    Hierarchy2 VARCHAR2(300),
    summary_name VARCHAR2(300),
    part_elements VARCHAR2(300),
    status VARCHAR2(300),
    issue_category VARCHAR2(300),
    relevance VARCHAR2(300),
    planned_duration FLOAT,
    description VARCHAR2(4000),
    precondition VARCHAR2(300),
    priority NUMBER(3,0),
    assignee VARCHAR2(300),
    expected_result VARCHAR2(300),
    editor VARCHAR2(300),
    modification_date DATE,
    dok_ref VARCHAR2(4000),
    activity VARCHAR2(4000),
    ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR NUMBER(9,0)
    );


    INSERT INTO Project.ITERATIONS
     select 
      NULL as Issue_Id,
      iter.testfall_id as iteration_id,  
    iter.testfall_id  || ' ' || iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER || ' ' || iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER_BESCHREIBU as content_of_iteration,
    tfb.TESTFALL_ID as parent_id,

      'Iteration' as Issue_type,
      NULL as Hierarchy1,
      NULL as Hierarchy2, 
      'Iteration' ||' '|| iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR  || ' - ' || tfb.FALL_BEZEICHNUNG  as summary_name,
      NULL as part_elements,
      NULL as status,



          NULL as issue_category,

          NULL as relevance,

       /*  CASE (iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR) WHEN 0 THEN iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER
         ELSE '' 
         END
         as naglowek,*/

      NULL as planned_duration,

     ' |' || Replace(iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER,';','|') || ' | |'  ||iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER_BESCHREIBU || ' |' as description,
      NULL as precondition,
      NULL as priority,
      NULL as assignee,
      NULL as expected_result,
      NULL as editor,
      NULL as modification_date,
      NULL as dok_ref,
     /* NULL as TESTSCHRITT_BEZEICHNUNG*/
    /*NULL as activity*/
    NULL  as activity,
    iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR as ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR

    FROM Project.TESTFALLBESCHREIBUNG tfb, Project.ITERATIONSPARAMETER iter

    where 
    iter.testfall_id =tfb.testfall_id (+)
    order by
    Issue_Id,
    iteration_id,
    iter.ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR ;


    SELECT 
    distinct tfb.TESTFALL_ID as Issue_Id,
    NULL as iteration_id,  
    NULL as content_of_iteration,
    NULL as parent_id,
      'Test_case' as Issue_type,
      REPLACE(globale.testbezeichnung, ' ','_') as Hierarchy1,
      REPLACE(voraus.voraussetzungs_bezeichnung,' ' , '_') as Hierarchy2, 
      CAST(FALL_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(150)) as summary_name,
      CAST(BETEILIGTE_ELEMENTE AS varchar(100)) as part_elements,
      status.testfall_status_beschreibung as status,



          (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '0 0 0' THEN ''
        ELSE '' END) ||
         (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '-1 0 0' THEN 'FEHLERFREIHEIT'
        ELSE '' END) ||
         (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '-1 -1 0' THEN 'FEHLERFREIHEIT WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '-1 -1 -1' THEN 'FEHLERFREIHEIT WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '0 -1 0' THEN 'WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '0 -1 -1' THEN 'WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT'
        ELSE '' END)||
        (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '-1 0 -1' THEN 'FEHLERFREIHEIT VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE FEHLERFREIHEIT || ' ' || WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT || ' ' || VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT WHEN '0 0 -1' THEN 'VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT'
        ELSE '' END) as issue_category,

         (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '0 0 0' THEN ''
        ELSE '' END) ||
         (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '-1 0 0' THEN 'ELEMENTTEST'
        ELSE '' END) ||
         (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '-1 -1 0' THEN 'ELEMENTTEST INTEGRATIONSTEST'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '-1 -1 -1' THEN 'ELEMENTTEST INTEGRATIONSTEST SYSTEMTEST'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '0 -1 0' THEN 'INTEGRATIONSTEST'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '0 -1 -1' THEN 'INTEGRATIONSTEST SYSTEMTEST'
        ELSE '' END)||
        (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '-1 0 -1' THEN 'ELEMENTTEST SYSTEMTEST'
        ELSE '' END) ||
        (CASE ELEMENTTEST || ' ' || INTEGRATIONSTEST || ' ' || SYSTEMTEST WHEN '0 0 -1' THEN 'SYSTEMTEST'
        ELSE '' END) as relevance,
     /* NULL as head, */

      tfb.GEPLANTER_AUFWAND as planned_duration,
      CAST(BESCHREIBUNG_TESTFALL AS varchar(4000)) as description,
      CAST(AUSGANGSSITUATION AS varchar(200)) as precondition,
      WICHTIGKEIT as priority,
      BEARBEITER as assignee,
      CAST(ERWARTETE_ERGEBNISSE AS varchar(200)) as expected_result,
      LETZTER_BEARBEITER as editor,
      DATUM_LETZTE_ÄNDERUNG as modification_date,
       Replace(LISTAGG( dokref.dokumentenreferenz, chr(10)) within group (order by dokref.dokumentenreferenz),' ','_') as dok_ref,
    steps.test_step as activity,
    NULL as ITERATIONSPARAMETER_NR





    FROM Project.TESTFALLBESCHREIBUNG tfb, Project.TEST_STEPS steps,Project.NM_TESTFALL_DOKUMENTENREFERENZ nmdokref,
    Project.DOKUMENTENREFERENZ dokref, Project.TESTFALL_STATUS status, Project.VORAUSSETZUNGEN voraus, Project.GLOBALE_ANGABEN globale,
    Project.NM_TESTFÄLLE_STICHWORTE stich, Project.STICHWORTE stichworte
    WHERE tfb.testfall_id=steps.test_case_id (+)
    AND tfb.testfall_id= nmdokref.testfall_id (+)
    AND nmdokref.dokumentenreferenz_id= dokref.dokumentenreferenz_id(+)
    AND tfb.testfall_status= status.testfall_status (+)
    AND tfb.voraussetzung_id=voraus.voraussetzung_id (+)
    AND voraus.tz_id= globale.tz_id (+)
    AND tfb.testfall_id= stich.testfall_id (+)
    AND stich.stichworte_id= stichworte.stichwort_id (+)







    GROUP BY  

      tfb.TESTFALL_ID,
      globale.testbezeichnung,
      status.testfall_status_beschreibung,
      voraus.voraussetzungs_bezeichnung,
      CAST(FALL_BEZEICHNUNG AS varchar(200)) ,
      CAST(BETEILIGTE_ELEMENTE AS varchar(200)),
      FEHLERFREIHEIT,
      WIDERSPRUCHSLOSIGKEIT,
      VOLLSTÄNDIGKEIT,
      ELEMENTTEST,
      INTEGRATIONSTEST,
      SYSTEMTEST,
      tfb.GEPLANTER_AUFWAND,
      CAST(BESCHREIBUNG_TESTFALL AS varchar(200)),
      CAST(AUSGANGSSITUATION AS varchar(200)),
      WICHTIGKEIT,
      BEARBEITER,
      CAST(ERWARTETE_ERGEBNISSE AS varchar(200)),
      LETZTER_BEARBEITER,
      DATUM_LETZTE_ÄNDERUNG,
      status.testfall_status_beschreibung,
      stichworte.stichwort,
      steps.test_step






     UNION ALL

    select * from Project.ITERATIONS
```